# GNU parallel is merging the ouput for multiple files into one. Why?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnu, gnu-parallel

I am running GNU parallel. Unlike the output in my other analyses the output for this one is weird.

My code:

```
# set the path of the required program
samtools=/usr/local/apps/samtools/0.1.19-gcc412/samtools
TempDir=/gpfs_common/share03/uncg/bkgiri/apps/temp_files/


# run the process for 4 samples in 4 different cores
parallel --tmpdir ${TempDir} --jobs 4 ${samtools} view -b -q 40 realigned_{}.bam -L DNA_Samples.Passed_Variants.Final.bed > realigned_{}Filtered.bam ::: ms01e ms02g ms03g ms04h
```

- I was expecting 4 different output files for each input, each named as realigned_ms01eFiltered.bam, realigned_ms02gFiltered.bam  etc.
- But, I am getting a one large file named as, `realigned_{}Filtered.bam`. I never encountered this problem before with other tools.

**I also tried doing:**

```
parallel --tmpdir ${TempDir} --jobs 4 '${samtools} view -b -q 40 realigned_{}.bam -L DNA_Samples.Passed_Variants.Final.bed > realigned_{}Filtered.bam' ::: ms01e ms02g ms03g ms04h

# which now gives me another type of error
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `>` is interpreted as redirection by the shell even before `parallel` can see it.

Comment: I was guessing if that was the problem. But, I have tried several tweak but my problem isn't fixed yet. Any suggestions ?

Comment: See the `--files` or `--results` options of `parallel`; or write a wrapper to samtools that expects the output file name as a parameter (if it's not possible to specify it directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, mentioned by @choroba: > is interpreted as redirection by the shell even before parallel can see it.

**So, I found two way of working out this problem at the end.**

1. **Method A:** We can either interpret the whole command within `" "` which I think is functionally more efficient.

   ```
   parallel --tmpdir ${TempDir} --jobs 4 "${samtools} view -b -q 40 realigned_{}.bam -L DNA_Samples.Passed_Variants.Final.bed > realigned_{}Filtered.bam" ::: ms01e ms02g ms03g ms04h
   ```
2. **Method B:** Or, we can interpret the output within `" "`. This allows `>` to be interpreted as text which when pipedin as stdin work as output rather than redirection.

   ```
   parallel --tmpdir ${TempDir} --jobs 4 ${samtools} view -b -q 40 realigned_{}.bam -L DNA_Samples.Passed_Variants.Final.bed ">" realigned_{}Filtered.bam ::: ms01e ms02g ms03g ms04h
   ```

I tested both method and both methods give me exactly the same result. So, either one is safe to call.

Thanks,